# Not able to declare 'CvANN_MLP’ object

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to use openCV CvANN_MPL. I'm getting below error. I've include all necessary header files, but getting below error.

```
error: ‘CvANN_MLP’ has not been declared
```

snip of code :

```
CvANN_MLP::CvANN_MLP nnetwork;
nnetwork.create(layers, CvANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM,0.6,1);
```

Comment: Are you including the corresponding OpenCV headers? Try to be more specific, show your code (the relevant parts), tell what OpenCV version you are using, etc

Comment: there is no CvANN_MLP namespace. it is just: `CvANN_MLP nnetwork;`

Comment: @KeillRandor I'm using opencv 3.0.0

Comment: @berak what is the namespace of CvANN_MLP?

Answer (score 2):

if you're using opencv3.0, there's no more ‘CvANN_MLP’ at all, the interfaces changed wrt. 2.4

you will have to use:

```
// note: additional namespace !
cv::Ptr<cv::ml::ANN_MLP> ann = cv::ml::ANN_MLP::create(); 
ann->setLayerSizes(layer_sizes);
ann->train(features, cv::ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labels);
```

Comment: wht is layer_sizes? Is it no of layer or wht?

Comment: please [look at the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d0/dce/classcv_1_1ml_1_1ANN__MLP.html#a79731c3fd3168e28eb3c3bba7a2caa94)

Comment: [I thought this link pretty handy](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html#tutorial_transition_hints_ml) to explain the differences between Opencv2.x and 3.0 as it relates to Machine Learning Module (which is where the ANN_MLP stuff comes from)